# Asp.net Editable Gridview having multiple rows

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I am building a asp.net form having numerous text boxes and a editable grid. How can I add a grid view having text boxes, dropdown in each row and  accepts data from client and shows second row when user fill the first for further entry

And also saving the data of the form and multiple rows of grid at once

My application also populates dropdown list from sql server database

Answer (score 0):

Go through the link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/467788/Dynamically-adding-and-deleting-rows-from-ASP-NET

You requirement will achieve.